# How to get hyperlinks dynamically in Microsoft Access Reports?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-reports

In a MS Access Report, I am trying to create a hyperlink that would take a user webpage. The URL is dependent on a data field in my database.

In my report, I have added the hyperlink control and used the popup to enter the hyperlink.

When I use the Hyperlink Builder, to dynamically set the value of one of the parameters, I get a garbage url that does not work.  The URL that is returned is :

> file:///C|/Users/gh/Dropbox%20(Bar01%20College)/BW%20Demo%20Project/="https://baruch.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_8uZm3rAnSWPE9gN?DocumentID="
>   & [documentID] & "&TransmittedScore=ENG_2100"

[image: MS Access Edit Hyperlink Popup, Hyperlink with dynamic value that does not work]

The expected result would be to have the URL that is customized based on the record where my parameter DocumentID would be equal to the value of my documentID field.

> https://baruch.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_8uZm3rAnSWPE9gN?DocumentID=ZuluTest&TransmittedScore=ENG_2100

If I paste the expected URL into the address field, the URL parses properly: 
[image: MS Access Edit Hyperlink Popup, Hyperlink with static value that does work]

*The requirement of this project is that the links need to be clickable when exported to PDF.*

*Note: I have previously posted this question to https://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=2057701 and looking for additional assistance.*

Comment: I test both Hyperlink type field as well as hyperlink constructed by expression in textbox ControlSource property. Both result in a clickable link in PDF. I used the link posted in your narrative.

Comment: If you want a hyperlink based on data in table, don't use Hyperlink type field and therefore not the hyperlink builder. As already advised in referenced link, use an expression in textbox ControlSource.

Comment: @June7 Thank you. Working with TheDBGuy I was able to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Working with *TheDBGuy* on the UtterAccess forum (URL in my original question). The solution that came up was to use an UNBOUND Text Box, setting the property of **Is Hyperlink** = *Yes*. 
Then in the ControlSource property, built the URL string in the format of `="<DISPLAY TEXT>#URL"`

So the value would have been:

`="ENG 2100#https://baruch.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_8uZm3rAnSWPE9gN?DocumentID="& [documentID] & "&TransmittedScore=ENG_2100"`